# Кто сейчас предлагает бесплатный Tier в месяц кроме Amazon AWS и Google Cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud

Подскажите, какие крупные компании кроме амазон AWS и гугл клауд дают бесплатные вычислительные мощности? Например у AWS дает 400тыс секунд вычислений в месяц бесплатно, и google cloud дает подобно.

Есть ли подобные аналоги?